# Does the function $x \mapsto \sqrt{1-x^2}$ have a name?

Tags: calculus, geometry, terminology, triangles, education

Define a function

$$[-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

$$x \mapsto x^\perp$$

as follows:

$$x^\perp = \sqrt{1-x^2}.$$

I find this function to be pedagogically useful, to help students grasp certain facts about the circular functions and relationships between circles and right-angled triangles.

> **Question.** Does $x^\perp$ have an accepted name and/or notation?

I might as well tell you guys how I use it.

I begin by drawing a right-angled triangle with hypotenuse $1$. One side is labelled $x$. I ask the student to write find the length of the other side, and to begin by labelling the other side $y$. So they solve $x^2+y^2=1^2$ for $y$, and obtain $y = \sqrt{1-x^2}$. I tell them: lets call $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ the "Pythagorean complement" of $x$, and denote it $x^\perp$. I get them to compute a few examples until they've internalized the meaning of the formula. Then we graph the whole thing an it ends up looking like a half-circle. Hmmm, why is that? I get them to compute the length of the vector $(x,x^\perp),$ and sure enough it's $1$. That makes sense; we obtained $x^\perp$ by solving the equation $|(x,y)| = 1$ subject to the constraint $y \geq 0$, and then defining $y= x^\perp$. So it stands to reason that $(x,x^\perp)$ is always a point on the upper half of the unit circle.

Then we move to trigonometry. I complete the half-circle to a unit circle, and draw a vertical line at $x=\frac{1}{2}$. What are the $y$-values of the points of intersection? The student puzzles out that these are $\pm x^\perp$. I get them to write those two points as $(x,x^\perp)$ and $(x,-x^\perp)$. To see why this makes sense, we go back to the equation $x^2+y^2 = 1^2$ and solve it properly, with no assumptions on $y$ beyond being a real number and satisfying this equation. We get $$x^2+y^2 = 1^2 \iff y^2=1-x^2 \iff y \in \pm \sqrt{1-x^2} \iff y \in \pm x^\perp.$$

Seems to make sense.

I get the student to compute a few examples:

$$0^\perp = 1, \qquad \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^\perp = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, \qquad \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^\perp = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \qquad \mathrm{etc.} $$

I explain that this pairs off each point in $[0,1]$ with another point, such that the ordered pair $(x,x^\perp)$ is always on the unit circle in the first quadrant. We discuss whether or not $x \mapsto x^\perp$ is an involution. On the domain $[0,1]$, it is. But on $[-1,1]$, all we can say is that $(x^\perp)^\perp = |x|.$

Finally, we get to solving some trigonometric equations. In order to avoid complex numbers, I define $\mathrm{wrap} \,\theta = (\cos \theta, \sin \theta).$ The student computes $\|\mathrm{wrap}\,\theta\|$ and checks that this is always $1$. So $\mathrm{wrap}$ lands us on the unit circle; it "wraps" the real line around the circle. Finally we try to solve some trigonometric equations. We proceed like so:

> TFAE
>
> $\cos \theta = \frac{1}{2}$
>
> $\mathrm{wrap}\, \theta = \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) \vee \mathrm{wrap} \,\theta = \left(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$
>
> $\left(\theta \in \frac{\pi}{3}+2\pi \mathbb{Z}\right) \vee \left(\theta \in \frac{5\pi}{3}+2\pi \mathbb{Z}\right)$
>
> $\theta \in \left(\frac{\pi}{3}+2\pi \mathbb{Z}\right) \cup \left(\frac{5\pi}{3}+2\pi \mathbb{Z}\right)$

I think students appreciate this kind of reasoning, because it helps them understand why there's two families of solutions to each of these problems.

For more advanced students, you can show them things like:

$$(\cos\theta)^\perp = |\sin \theta|, \qquad (\sin\theta)^\perp = |\cos \theta|$$

$$\cos (\mathrm{arcsin}(x)) = \sin (\mathrm{arccos}(x)) = x^\perp$$

$$\frac{d}{dx} \mathrm{arcsin}(x) = \frac{1}{x^\perp}, \qquad \frac{d}{dx} \mathrm{arccos}(x) = -\frac{1}{x^\perp}, \quad \frac{d}{dx} \mathrm{arcsec} = \frac{1}{|x|x^\perp}$$

Etc.

You can also give them some challenge problems related to the geometry of the circle. For instance, ask them to conjecture a value for $\int_{x=-1}^1 x^\perp$.

**Addendum.** I just learned that this function shows up [when sums of inverse trigonometric functions are involved](https://www.emathzone.com/tutorials/math-results-and-formulas/formulas-for-sum-and-difference-of-inverse-trigonometric-functions.html).

In particular:

$$\sin^{-1}(a) \pm \sin^{-1}(b) = \sin^{-1}(ab^\perp \pm a^\perp b)$$

$$\cos^{-1}(a) \pm cos^{-1}(b) = \cos^{-1}(ab \mp a^\perp b^\perp)$$

Comment: I think about my precalculus students and the content of this question, and I would *definitely* pay money to be a fly on the wall in whatever class this is for :) If there isn't a name for the function (I wouldn't expect a common one, at least), I'd vote for "(upper) semicircle function."

Comment: @pjs36, thanks for the kind words. I've thought of calling it something like that, but then what do you call $x^\perp$? The "upper unit semicircle value of $x$" just seems... well, long-winded, to say the least!

Comment: Yes, I could see it getting clunky unless you have a really short name. The good news is that with such a holistic approach, one would hope that students understand the importance of the (centered) *unit* circle, over other possible radii. Plus the notation $x^\perp$, lacking a parameter, suggests you don't  intend to generalize to other radii (at least in a significant enough way to warrant habitually highlighting the "unit" aspect of the semicircle). So maybe find a way to work "height" in there somewhere, for the output. But it would still be clunky...

Comment: Well constructed lesson plan (+1).

Comment: Is it really worth giving it a name?

Comment: I see why you might give it a name for a particular lesson, to retain consistency and hopefully prevent confusion for students. But, it honestly seems unnecessary giving it a special name or notation.

Comment: I propose $\text{coas}$, for *cosine of arc sine*.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, that's clever!

Comment: This gives rise to a theorem: $\text{coas}(x)\equiv\text{soac}(x)$. ;-)

Comment: $\text{arch}$ migh be a better choice.

Comment: I wouldn't use "coas" - in speech it could get confused with "cos".

Comment: Precedent for calling the function a semicircle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_semicircle_distribution

Answer (score 5):

I would call it a semicircle.

But I need thirty characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the notation may refer as orthogonality, in  the dot product you say that two vectors in $\mathbb{R^n}$ are orthogonal if their dot product is $0$. You can generalize this idea for another vector spaces, this is called an inner product space, in this case you can define the inner product of two functions to be $$\int_{-1}^{1} f(x)g(x)dx$$ and you say that$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are orthogonal if that definite integral is $0$. Check it out!! And you can see tha the inner product between $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ is $0$ and also the inner product between x and $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is $0$. So I would call tha function the orthogonal or perpendicular complement of x

Comment: That's cool, but I'm pretty sure there's many functions on $[-1,1]$ that are orthogonal to $x$. The relevant vector space is denoted $L_2[-1,1]$, and it's huge.